# Rails 3 and PHP cooperation issue

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding

I am trying to write a service using php5 and consuming it using Rails 3.
Here is what I do.

**PHP:**

```
// $DATA is an associative array that contains an Ukrainian characters.
// I am converting all of values with Ukrainien characters to utf-8 using **utf8_encode** function

header('Content-Type: json; charset=utf8');
echo json_encode($DATA);
exit;
```

PHP converts strings like **\u00ca\u00e2\u00e8\u00f2\u00e0\u00ed\u00f6\u00b3\u00ff**

**RAILS:**

```
url = URI.parse("http://127.0.0.1/searchInvStat/showclaimdetails.php?app_n=#{@claim.claim_db[:app_number]}")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
   http.request(req)
}

@states = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode( res.body )
```

But on result page I get a string like **Îïèñ âèíàõîäó (ÊÌ)** instead of **Опис винаходу (КМ)**

Can someone help me?

Comment: What happens if you open the PHP script in a browser? Does it look okay there?

Comment: Yes, I think so, I see u00ca\u00e2\u00e8\u00f2\u00e0\u00ed\u00f6\u00b3\u00ff string, it's ok I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

Instead of using `json_encode($DATA)` you should use `iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $DATA['OUTDOCS'][$i]['regNumb']);`